# Expansion of alias “a“ failed；’version’ is not a git command

Tags: git, macos

What’s the problem with this on macOS ?

Input:

```
git config —global alias.a version
```

Error:

```
Expansion of alias “a“ failed；’version’ is not a git command
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a `—` character ("em dash") instead of two hypens `--`.

Having corrected that, it works for me:

```
$ git config --global alias.a version
$ git a
git version 2.7.1
$
```

Comment: In your question above though (and even in your comment) you have an em-dash (`—`). It may just be whatever software you are using to type the question that is causing this substitution, but please make sure you post the actual command when asking a question, ideally using copy and paste, and make sure you disable automatic substitution of smart quotes, typographical dashes, etc, otherwise you will just confuse people.